# Adding exceptions to recurring meeting in Office365 API(using REST)

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

I have a custom calendar, I have created a reoccurring event in that calendar.
Now I am trying to implement the functionality where by user should be able to move an instance of reoccurrance to another datetime (just as we can do in outlook). I ham using PATH to update the meeting startdatetime and enddatetime , but I get following error.

---

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
{"error":{"code":"ErrorOccurrenceCrossingBoundary","message":"Modified occurrence is crossing or overlapping adjacent occurrence."}}

I have not tried to do this using EWS yet, if someone has any pointer for that is also welcome to respond.

Help!

Thanks
Harshit

Answer (score 1):

We only permit one instance of a recurring series per day.  Most likely the issue is that you are moving an instance to the same day as another instance of the same series, and the server is rejecting the request.  If you can include the date/time and recurrence details of the series and the specific instance you are moving, and what date/time you are moving to, we can tell for sure.